# SFTP using Apache commons

Tags: java, sftp, apache-commons

I am looking for code to do SFTP using Java. I found [a tutorial](http://blog.iparissa.com/javasnippets/using-commons-vfs-to-do-sftp/) using Apache VFS but it is not helping me much.

If anyone has any ideas or code. Please provide it.

Comment: The links looks pretty self-explanatory. What have you tried?

Comment: have you tried [googling](https://www.google.hr/search?q=apache+commons+sftp+how+to&sugexp=chrome,mod=16&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=hr&sclient=psy-ab&q=apache+commons+sftp+how+to&oq=apache+commons+sftp+how+to&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.146856.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.twgLTkwKqVY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=c6b16acea7beb2ec&biw=1600&bih=764)? this is one [result](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/SimpleSftpFileDownload)

Comment: user owned his own patch version,I dont want in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jftp](http://j-ftp.sourceforge.net/).

It includes more protocols and is easy to understand.